# Where is the error in this python code?

Tags: python-3.x

[image: img]

First few examples:

```
Input:
 10
 1
 4 5 6
Output:
 6
```

another one:

```
Input:
 10
 2
 3 3 3
 7 7 4
Output:
 4
```

I put this code it is correct for some cases but not for all where is the problem?

```
n = int(input())
q = int(input())
z = 0
repeat = 0
ans = 0
answ = []
arrx = []
arry = []
for i in range(q):
    maxi = 0
    x,y,w = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    x,y = x+1, y+1
    if((arrx.count(x)>=1)):
        index = arrx.index(x)
        if(y==arry[index]):
            if(answ[index]==ans):
                repeat += answ[index]
                z = answ[index]
    arrx.append(x)
    arry.append(y)
    if((w>x or w>y) or (w>(n-x) or w>(n-y))):
        maxi = max(x, y, (n-x), (n-y))
    if(((x>=w) or (y>=w)) or (((n-x)>=w) or ((n-y)>=w))):
        maxi = w
    ans = max(ans, maxi)
    answ.append(ans)
    if(ans>z):
        repeat = 0
print(ans+repeat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see with your code is you are handling the data as two one dimensional arrays, `arrx` and `arry`, when the problem calls for a two dimensional array.  You should be able to print out your data structure and see the heat map for the volcanoes.  For the first example, you've got a single hot volcano in the middle of the map:

```
10
1
4 5 6

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Where the hottest (6) spot is obviously the one volcano itself.  For the second example, you've got two cooler volcanos:

```
10
2
3 3 3
3 3 3
7 7 4

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Where the hot spot will either be the hotter of the two volcanos or potentially some spot that falls in their overlap that gets heated by both.  In this case, the overlap spots don't get hotter than the hotest (4) volcano.  But if the volcanoes were closer, one or more might have.